Unusual High Ionizing Radiation Levels Detected in Eastern USA
I've been monitoring radiation levels using a Terra-P MKS-05 IP30 dosimeter and have observed some alarmingly high spikes that I cannot fully explain. I'd like to see if anyone may have some insights or have seen similar experiences. There almost seems to be a correlation with solar weather alerts I've been getting, but they are not direct and, according to all of my research, this should not be happening at my elevation or at night...
Observations:

A significant spike of 860 µSv/h was recorded around 1:28 or 1:29 AM on May 3, along with multiple other spikes exceeding 100 µSv/h around the same time.

At 1:32 AM, another spike reached approximately 400 µSv/h.

Later, a spike of 700 µSv/h was also recorded.

For context, the typical background radiation level in my area rarely exceeds 2 µSv/h.


Additional Details:

My dosimeter's alarm, set at the highest threshold (9.99 µSv/h), has been constantly triggered, to the point where I've had to remove the batteries to stop the incessant beeping.

These are not isolated incidents; such spikes have been occurring frequently, almost like undergoing a daily chest x-ray for the past month.


Any insights or other observations that might correlate or extrapolate into potential sources of such data?
